# Using fwrite, want to skip writing three items in A between each write

Tags: image, matlab, file-io, color-space

So, I'm doing some image processing in MATLAB, and attempting to save a file out to a y4m format with colorspace 4:2:0.

Basically, what it comes down to is I want to use fwrite, but I want to be able to skip a certain number of items in the vector that's writing. Is there an easy way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [tools](http://sprljan.com/nikola/matlab/yuv.html) for doing this already.

If you insist on doing things yourself (I do, since I can't be bothered paying for the separate toolboxes), you can always make a new vector containing only the elements you need to write.  Assuming that you have YUV 4:4:4 and you want to write it as YUV 4:2:0:

- Split `yuv444` into it's separate Y', Cb, Cr components
- Write `Y'` as is, using `fwrite`
- Downsample `Cb` and `Cr` by a factor of two to get `Cb_down` and `Cr_down`
- Write `Cb_down` and `Cr_down` using `fwrite` to the same open file handle

Comment: *Method Not Implemented GET to /nikola/matlab/yuv.html not supported.*

Comment: @zellus: weird.  what browser are you using?  i tried chrome at my lab and IE (*gasp*) at home, and everything works.

Comment: firefox on debian and safari on os x.

Answer (score 0):

[Logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) from '*Steve on Image Processing*' might be a good starter for your aim.